# How to calculate number of games to be played?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

A game is played by throwing two standard six-sided dice into the air once. The sum of uppermost numbers are added together and if the sum is greater than 8, the player wins $5. Determine

(1) the probability of winning at least $15 in at most 5 games.

(Assume the probability of playing 3,4 or 5 games is the same $\frac{1}{3}$ for each case.)

(2) The minimum number of games to be played so that the probability of winning at least $15 is greater than 0.47. Justify your answer.

The probability that sum is greater than 8 is $\frac{10}{36}.$
I tries to use binomial distribution as

probability = $\binom{5}{3}(\frac{10}{36})^3 (\frac{26}{36})^2  + \binom{5}{4} (\frac{10}{36})^4 (\frac{26}{36})  + \binom{5}{5} (\frac{10}{36})^5.$

Comment: Begin with determining the probability to win the game

Comment: Please edit your question and add some info on what you have tried.

Comment: Do you intend \comb[5]3 to be the number of combinations of three objects out of five?  You can write that as {5 \choose 3} which gives ${5 \choose 3}$

Comment: or `\binom{5}{3}` which gives $\binom{5}{3}$ too.

Comment: Your last line would be correct if you were guaranteed to play $5$ games.  You have ignored the parenthetical line that says you might stop earlier.  The same approach will work for fewer games, but you have to incorporate it.

Comment: @RossMillikan So how sholud i approach??

Comment: $(2)$ makes no sense : the number of games we need to win 15 dollars is at least 3, as we can win 5 per game. But you have to know something before you can answer it: are you allowed to play as many games as you like? So play 3 games (maybe lose 2, win 1) and play 2 more etc., stopping whenever you have 15? (2) as it stands cannot be answered confidently. 0.47 seems bogus.

Comment: I think you should roll a three sided die for how many games you will play.  You have computed the chance you win 15 if you get to play five games.  A similar but simpler expression will give the chance if you get to play four games, and a very simple one the chance if you play three.  Then you have to average the results.  It is a strange question.  The two answers do exactly this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if we play *one* game the chance we win is $p:=\frac{10}{36} = \frac{5}{18}$ (there are $4+3+2+1$ throws with sum $9$ to $12$ and $36$ total throws).

We're doing a series of independent trials of this same experiment, so we're working with a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). So far so good.

Let the number of games in the first question be $N$. Then $P(N=3)= P(N=5)=P(N=4)=\frac13$ (given), and the number of games won ($X$) when the value of $N$ is fixed is a binomial distribution, so we condition on the value of $N$.

We're interested in $P(X \ge 3)$, the only way to win at least $15 (there is no cost to playing, so that is straightforward).

$$P(X\ge3) = P(X\ge 3\mid N=3)P(N=3) + P(X\ge 3\mid N=4)P(N=4) + P(X\ge 3\mid N=5)P(N=5)$$

by the total probability law.

Now we apply the different binomial distributions with the same $p$ and different $n$:

$$P(X \ge 3\mid N=3)=p^3$$

$$P(X\ge 3\mid N=4)P(N=4)= \binom{4}{3}p^3(1-p) + p^4$$

and the one you calculated:

$$P(X\ge 3\mid N=5)P(N=5) = \binom{5}{3}p^3(1-p)^2 + \binom{5}{4}p^4(1-p) + p^5$$

So add these and divide by $3$ for the common probabilities $\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the probability of winning the game is $\frac{5}{18}$. To get this, calculate the ways to get $9, 10, 11, \text{or } 12$ and divide by $36$. This means the probability of losing is $\frac{13}{18}.$

For (1), I would just use casework.

- Winning in 3 games: There is only one way, and that is winning every single game. The probability is $(\frac{5}{18})^3$.
- Winning in 4 games: You can either win $3$ or $4$ games. Winning $4$ games means you win every single one, with probability $(\frac{5}{18})^4$. Winning $3$ games means you win every single one except one. This probability is $(\frac{5}{18})^3\cdot \frac{13}{18}$, but there are also $\binom{4}{1} = 4$ ways to arrange the wins and losses. So it's actually $(\frac{5}{18})^3\cdot \frac{13}{18}\cdot 4.$
- Winning in 5 games: You can win $3$, $4$, or $5$ games. Winning $5$ is a $(\frac{5}{18})^5$ chance, winning $4$ is a $(\frac{5}{18})^4\cdot \frac{13}{18}\cdot \binom{5}{1}$ chance, and winning $3$ is a $(\frac{5}{18})^3\cdot (\frac{13}{18})^2\cdot \binom{5}{2}$ chance. (The reasons for this are the same as before.)

Adding everything gets $0.22425760808$, about a $22.426\%$ chance. Not very likely!

You can use a similar approach for (2).